# What counts as a yes/no question?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to decide which answer to accept for [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55216/batman-vs-4-villains). My problem stems from disagreement as to what constitutes a yes/no question, in particular with boboquack's answer. Upon checking, I discovered that there doesn't seem to be a consensus as to what a yes/no question entails. Any thoughts as to what qualifies as yes/no in the general sense?

Answer (score 3):

I think the core of your question here is around the conversation that happened in comments, wherein one user raised the following objection:

> [...] the problem with this solution is that the question as asked is not a yes or no question. It's asking the answerer to select a value from a list. Take, for example, the question, "Is your favorite word 'Yes', 'No', or 'Potato'?" If the answerer's favorite word happens to be Potato, how would they answer truthfully? Simple! They would say "Yes," as in "Yes, my favorite word is one of 'Yes', 'No', or 'Potato'." If their favorite word is "Proscuitto", they would truthfully answer "No." This solution misinterprets what a "Yes or No question" is. – [oobug](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55216/batman-vs-4-villains#comment170415_55220)

To which the solution's writer rebuts:

> @oobug The question is not: "Is X, Y or Z?" The question is: "Will X, Y, or Z occur?". If one of X, Y and Z occur, then the only correct answer is yes (though they might lie and say no). If none of X, Y nor Z occur, then the only correct answer is no (though they might lie and say yes). If they are telling the truth and one of X, Y and Z occur when they say no but none occur if they say yes, there is no logical answer. If they are lying and one of X, Y and Z occur when they say yes but none occur if they say no, there is no logical answer. [....]  – [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55216/batman-vs-4-villains#comment170445_55220)

If a question effectively asks "Is <foo> true?" then it's a Yes/No question, even for more or less arbitrarily complex expressions of <foo>.  In this case, while the question involves an expression that amounts to, if I read it right, "((A and X) or (B and Y) or (C and ((Y and Y') or (X and X'))))", it still boils down to a multi-part logical expression that can be evaluated as true or false, and then a final answer of Yes or No given.

Note that even a nominally Yes/No question doesn't necessarily admit only those two answers; if I ask you "Is it noisy right now where I am?" the question logically can only have a Yes or a No as an answer, but "I don't know" is nevertheless a valid response to such a question, as I daresay you can't answer that with any degree of accuracy.  Similarly there are questions for which the conditions being evaluated lead to logical inconsistencies for certain answers, meaning those answers cannot meaningfully be given.  That doesn't make the question any less of a Yes/No question.  "Are you alive?" is a yes/no question, even though you cannot give "No" as a literal, truthful answer.

Comment: There might be a disconnect between your last example and the description preceding it. "Are you alive?" has two answers. One answer is false and the other is true. Neither answer leads to a logical inconsistency.

Comment: I think it's `Y&&y||X&&x`, but otherwise (comment may just be a bit biased) great answer.

Comment: Strongly agree with Rubio: the questions in boboquack's solution are yes/no questions despite their complexity. (I haven't looked at the answer in enough detail to verify its correctness, so I am not claiming OP should accept that answer. But it shouldn't be rejected on the grounds that its questions are not yes/no questions.)

Comment: I would disagree that the question in boboquack''s answer complies with "it still boils down to a multi-part logical expression that can be evaluated as true or false, and then a final answer of Yes or No given." The answer explicitly states that it can force a pass via a head-exploding question.

Comment: @Apep Just found your comment. No, that part isn't quite right. Maybe a better alternative is just 'a multi-part logical expression which can be evaluated and either a final answer of yes or no given or a logical contradiction found'.